# Android - How to get views behind another view?

Tags: android

I have a use case where one view is on top of another. Is there anyway to programmatically get all views that are behind the view on top? I would like to know if I can get list of views that are overlapped by the current view

Comment: In your xml file you can use Elevation property for your views.

Comment: Just iterate over all views, find their locationOnScreen and use that to create a Rect for each of them, then filter that list based on some simple geometry (rectangle overlap)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the list of all occluding views with same parent, we check intersection and visibility of all views on top of the current view:

```java
 public static ArrayList<View> getOccludingViewsOf(View view){
        ArrayList<View> occludingList=new ArrayList<>();
        ViewGroup parent=((ViewGroup)view.getParent());
        int viewIndex=parent.indexOfChild(view);
        int viewSiblingCount=parent.getChildCount();
        Rect currentBound=getBoundary(view); 
        for (int i=viewIndex+1;i<viewSiblingCount;i++){
            View view_i= parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (view_i.getVisibility()==VISIBLE && currentBound.intersect(getBoundary(view_i))){
                occludingList.add(view_i);
            }
        }
        return occludingList;
    }
```

To get the boundary of each view:

```java
public static Rect getBoundary(View view){
        int[] pos = new int[2];
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
        return new Rect(pos[0], pos[1],
                pos[0] + view.getMeasuredWidth(), pos[1] + view.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

To check occlusion with views that have other roots (different parent), include them too (of course if their root are on top of the root of the current view).

Also if custom draw ordering of the parent is enable, instead of view index, we should check the drawing orders of views.

---

### Changing Orders Of View

If you want the view to be the last child on it's parent, Use:

```java
view.bringToFront();
```

Also, to change the order of view, first remove it from parent and then add it by your desire index:

```java
parentView.removeView(view);
parentView.addView(view,index);
```

Comment: I am looking for something different. I would like to know if I can get list of views that are overlapped by the current view

Comment: do you mean views with the same parent as the current view, or all  views in activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `FrameLayout` then views will cover each other by order of define after another.
but there is another way to do that is `android:translationZ` to translate by z-order.

you can alos use `view.bringToFront();` but it can only bring the view to the top of all views and you can not manage z index orders.

Comment: I am looking for something different. I would like to know if I can get list of views that are overlapped by the current view